# Extra argument 'where' in call

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on removing an item from an array in swift, and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

My code is:

```
var itemToRemove = list[indexPath.item]
selectedCasesArray.removeAll(where: { $0 == itemToRemove })
```

There code is in a CollectionView's `didSelect` function.

`itemToRemove` is of type `CaseFormat` and `selectedCaseArray` is of type `[CaseFormat]`.

Why doesn't this work? Apple's documentation allows it in Swift 4.2+, and I'm on Swift 5

---

I was asked to show how `CaseFormat` is declared:

```
class CaseFormat {

var id : Int
var imageName : String
var isSelected : Bool
var solve : String
var testTicks : Int

init(id : Int, imageName : String, isSelected : Bool, solve : String, testTicks : Int) {
    self.id = id
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.isSelected = isSelected
    self.solve = solve
    self.testTicks = testTicks
}

}
```

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Swift 5, and I've tried on Xcode 10 and 11

Comment: are the items `Equatable`?

Comment: That's weird. Is `selectedCasesArray` declared as `var`?

Comment: I would try rewriting to `selectedCasesArray = selectedCasesArray.filter { $0 != itemToRemove }` just to check the error message.

Comment: `Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two 'CaseFormat' operands`.  And it's declared as a var, but I'm not sure if they're `Equatable` - what is that?

Comment: That means you can actually use `==` and `!=` on them. Swift doesn't understand what `==` means for `CaseFormat`. Please, show us how `CaseFormat` is declared.

Comment: If the ids are unique then you could do `removeAll(where: { $0.id == itemToRemove.id  }`

Comment: As you have the index path anyway, why not simply (and more efficient) `selectedCasesArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)`?

Comment: That won't work for what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Since `CaseFormat` is not `Equatable`, you cannot use `==` with it.

It's a class so maybe you want to compare references directly using `===`?

```
selectedCasesArray.removeAll(where: { $0 === itemToRemove })
```

If you want to really use `==`, you have to implement `Equatable`, e.g.:

```
extension CaseFormat: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: CaseFormat, rhs: CaseFormat) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Of course, the exact behavior should depend on your use case.

Comment: What is the difference between the `==` and `===` ?